# use routeprovider with variable with slashes

Tags: angularjs, route-provider

I have this url defined, /item/1231, but its possible to use a variable with slashes as itemID?

If my item id is 12/31, how could this work? does it have to be encoded into %2F?

/item/12/31

```
  $routeProvider.when('/item/:itemID', {
    templateUrl: 'item_view.html',
    controller: 'ItemControler'
```

From the doc:

> Route path (matched against $location.path). If $location.path
>   contains redundant trailing slash or is missing one, the route will
>   still match and the $location.path will be updated to add or drop the
>   trailing slash to exactly match the route definition.
>
> path can contain named groups starting with a colon: e.g. :name. All
>   characters up to the next slash are matched and stored in $routeParams
>   under the given name when the route matches. path can contain named
>   groups starting with a colon and ending with a star: e.g.:name*. All
>   characters are eagerly stored in $routeParams under the given name
>   when the route matches. path can contain optional named groups with a
>   question mark: e.g.:name?.
>
> For example, routes like /color/:color/largecode/:largecode*/edit
>   will match /color/brown/largecode/code/with/slashes/edit and extract:
>
> color: brown
>
> largecode: code/with/slashes.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider

But I havent managed to make it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as the documentation says it just needs and * to be added to ignore slashes.

```
 $routeProvider.when('/item/:itemID*', {
    templateUrl: 'item_view.html',
    controller: 'ItemControler'
```